# Accessing Javascript array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JavaScript array called *park_data* which the console shows as below.

Using Javascript, do I access the `title` of each park and display it?

```
[Object { title="Football Park", lat="55.8546658", lng="-4.241034300000024"}, 
 Object { title="Rugby Park", lat="55.864058", lng="-4.272685000000024"}]
```

Many thanks

Comment: What you have posted here is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: It's likely a console.log thing

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, it was indeed from the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < park_data.length; i++) {
    var title = park_data[i].title;
    // do stuff with title
}
```